# What does the syntax "|>" do in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am looking at someone's code that has "|>" in it. What does that syntax do in Julia and can someone link the Julia Docs for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commonly denoted as "pipe syntax", this syntax:

> Applies a function to the preceding argument. This allows for easy
>   function chaining.

An example from the official docs:

```
julia> [1:5;] |> x->x.^2 |> sum |> inv

0.01818181818181818
```

And the official Julia docs page where you can find the `|>` operator is [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.2/stdlib/base/#Base.:%7C%3E).

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that this is commonly called `pipe` syntax, and is similar to the shell where you do something like `ls my_dir | grep pattern`

Comment: Added that! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Worth notice that there exist a third party package (https://github.com/oxinabox/Pipe.jl) that highly extend the base pipe operator..